# SQL insert statement syntax error VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, insert, sql-insert

When i run this in my program it says there is a syntax error in my SQL statement but when i use the same statement in another form it works perfectly fine. This is the SQL statement with the syntax error:

```
shop.MakeQuery("INSERT INTO Shop (Shop_ID,Shop_Name,Address,Postcode,) " &
                   "VALUES (@ID,@Name,@Address,@Postcode)")
```

This is the SQL statement which works completely fine

```
shop.MakeQuery("INSERT INTO Shop (Shop_ID,Shop_Name,Address,Postcode,) " &
                           "VALUES (@ID,@Name,@Address,@Postcode)")
```

No other errors show up. All the field names are typed correctly there are no data type errors or conversions that do not work. Can someone tell me how the two statement are different in syntax?

Comment: They're not different, but `Postcode,` with a trailing comma is just plain wrong.  The only thing you should be concerned with is whether the _correct_ insert statement is working.  So, does that work?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Don't edit an existing question, invalidating the existing answer(s).

Answer (score 2):

I found syntax error in your query, In your column section you have added comma(,) at last column, try below code it will work

```
shop.MakeQuery("INSERT INTO Shop (Shop_ID,Shop_Name,Address,Postcode) " &
                           "VALUES (@ID,@Name,@Address,@Postcode)")
```